# How to achieve such layout with Angular Flex-Layout

Tags: angular, layout, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

how could i achieve this layout using Angular Flex-Layout?
[image: desired layout]

Since i'm using angular material. It seems that i need to use this flex-layout lib instead of bootstrap but the problem is that i can't get it working, so any help is welcome thanks.

*i'm not looking for responsiveness, if i can get this layout just as the image it would help-me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, install [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout).

Import layout module to your project/module:

```
import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';
...
@NgModule({
 imports: [
   ...
   FlexLayoutModule,
   ...
 ]
})
```

And finally, in the HTML:

```
<div fxLayout="row" style="height: 100%">
  <div style="background-color: red" fxFlex="20"></div>
  <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
    <div style="background-color: blueviolet" fxFlex></div>
    <div style="background-color: cornflowerblue" fxFlex></div>
    <div style="background-color: darkgray" fxFlex></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`fxFlex="20"` gives the first div 20% width. `fxFlex` with no params just spreads the height or width evenly between elements.